# Error trying mount a folder into docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

im trying mount my folder with code in my container, i wanna change my code in my host and see changes in guest, but the folder where i mount my code in guest is empty

[image: image 1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

**Text**
In first image im running

```
docker run --name discord -it -v /c/xampp/htdocs/software/js/Pasante- bot:/usr/app/code bot
```

In second image im in the folder /usr/app/code INSIDE the container, im doing ls but the folder is empty

In third image im running

```
docker inspect discord
```

Output:

```
"Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/c/xampp/htdocs/software/js/Pasante-bot",
            "Destination": "/usr/app/code",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you paste _as text_ what commands you’re running and what error messages you’re getting?  I’m having trouble following along with what’s going on in these screen shots.

Comment: Ok, in first image im running 

    docker run --name discord -it -v 
    /c/xampp/htdocs/software/js/Pasante- 
    bot:/usr/app/code bot

Comment: @DavidMaze i edit the original post for you